# Resque scheduler recurring job update issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, resque-scheduler

I have a recurring job in my application that runs every 2 hours that got updated recently, and it seems the scheduler somehow has cached or ignored the changes made to this job.

If I connect to the server via SSH and open the file I can see the changes, and if I run the the job through the rails console everything works fine. But when the scheduler runs the job after 2 hours, it omits a counter that was added on the changes.

Any ideas of what could be going on here?

`resque (1.23.0)`
`resque-scheduler (2.2.0)`

Comment: did you restarted resque not resque-scheduler after you made your changes if not then do it since resque had to be restarted on event of any code changes else it will use the old code

Comment: I restarted Resque and that did the trick, thanks @Viren

Comment: Do you mean restarting Resque worker?

Comment: Yeah, restart the worker @Konstantin that got it to work correctly.

Comment: @Viren please convert your comment into an answer